# Causal inference calculus (Bayesian Probability)

Tags: probability, statistics, bayesian, causal-diagrams, causality

Here is my **problem**:

> There is a causal Markovian model as follows.
>
> [image]
>
> By the definition of *interventional probability*, since $\text{do}(x)$ makes no edges between $X$ and $Z_1, Z_2$, we have
>
> $$
>  P(y\mid \text{do}(x)) =\sum_{z_1,z_2,z_3}P(z_1)P(z_2)P(z_3\mid z_1, z_2)P(y \mid z_2, z_3, x),
> > $$
> where $\text{do}(\cdot)$ is so-called do-calculus (Judea pearl, 2010).
>
> [image]
>
> Then show that the summation over $z_2$ is
> $$
>  P(y\mid \text{do}(x)) =\sum_{z_1, z_3} P(z_1)  P(z_3\mid z_1)P(y \mid z_1, z_3, x).
> $$

**Here is what is tried**.

To hold the equality of the above problem, we must have
$$
  \sum_{z_2} P(z_3 \mid z_1,z_2)P(y,z_2,z_3,x) 
$$
should be same with
$$
  P(y,z_1,z_3,x),
$$
but I don't know how this can happen.

Thanks,

*Reference: Judea Pearl, 2010, An Introduction to Causal Inference, The International Journal of Biostatistics, pp15-16*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that $z_1$ can be inserted in $P(y_1 \mid z_2, z_3, x)$ due to $z_2$ and $z_3$ are sufficient statistics.

$$
 P(y_1 \mid z_2, z_3, x) = P(y_1 \mid z_1, z_2, z_3, x)
$$

Therefore, the first equation becomes,
$$
 P(y_1 \mid \text{do}(x)) = \sum_{z_1,z_2,z_3}P(z_1)P(z_2)P(z_3\mid z_1,z_2)P(y_1 \mid z_1, z_2, z_3, x) \\
= \sum_{z_1,z_2,z_3}P(z_1, z_2, z_3)P(y_1 \mid z_1, z_2, z_3, x) \\
= \sum_{z_1,z_2,z_3}P(z_1, z_2, z_3)\frac{P(y_1, z_1, z_2, z_3, x)}{P(z_1, z_2, z_3, x)} \\
= \sum_{z_1,z_2,z_3}P(z_1, z_2, z_3)\frac{P(y_1, z_1, z_2, z_3, x)}{P(z_1, z_2, z_3)} \quad \text{(because X is forced to be constant x)} \\
= \sum_{z_1,z_2,z_3}P(y_1, z_1, z_2, z_3, x) \\
= \sum_{z_1,z_3}P(y_1, z_1, z_3, x) \\
= \sum_{z_1,z_3}P(z_1, z_3) \frac{P(y_1, z_1, z_3, x)}{P(z_1,z_3)} \\
= \sum_{z_1,z_3}P(z_1)P(z_1 \mid z_3)P(y_1\mid z_1, z_3, x)
$$